# Update columns in df2 based on df1 on index of date

Tags: python, pandas

I want to to have a data frame **df2** that will contain the values from **df1**.
Both data frames have an index of date.
Both data frames contain the same columns. I just want to update the columns of df2 if the index of df2 exists in df1.

**df1**

```
Symbol          K1     K2       K3   
Date                                      
2011-01-10     0.0     0.0     0.0    
2011-01-13 -1500.0     0.0  4000.0    
2011-01-26     0.0  1000.0     0.0
```

**df2**

```
                K1     K2       K3   

2011-01-10     0.0     0.0     0.0
2011-01-11     0.0     0.0     0.0      
2011-01-26     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Desired Output

```
                K1     K2       K3     

2011-01-10     0.0     0.0     0.0    
2011-01-11     0.0     0.0     0.0   
2011-01-26     0.0  1000.0     0.0
```

I tried this;

```
df2 = df2.join(df1, on=df1.index, how='left')
```

But received this error;

> raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask]) KeyError:
>   "Index([u'2011-01-10', u'2011-01-13', u'2011-01-26', u'2011-02-02',\n

Any help is more than welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the common intersection on the indexes and use `combine_first`.

```
df = df.loc[df.index.intersection(df2.index)].combine_first(df2)

print(df)
Symbol       K1      K2   K3
2011-01-10  0.0     0.0  0.0
2011-01-11  0.0     0.0  0.0
2011-01-26  0.0  1000.0  0.0
```

---

**Details**

```
idx = df.index.intersection(df2.index)
print(idx)
Index(['2011-01-10', '2011-01-26'], dtype='object')

print(df.loc[idx])
Symbol       K1      K2   K3
2011-01-10  0.0     0.0  0.0
2011-01-26  0.0  1000.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. However, it is not working. Everything that is being printed is 0. like the original df2.

Comment: @Codinghierarchy What! Can you add some more data that reproduces your actual problem? As you can see, it works for this mini-dataset. Please check your variable names and everything else.

Comment: I added it like:
df2= df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(df2.index)].combine_first(df2)

Comment: @Codinghierarchy Should've worked. What is `df1.index.intersection(df2.index)` showing?

Comment: @Codinghierarchy Without data, I can't help :-( Try the other user's merge answer that I helped them with and see if that works for you.

Comment: Oh sorry, it shows empty index.Index([], dtype='object')

Comment: @Codinghierarchy Aha, check your indexes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to merge on indices:

```
df3 =df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=("","_"), how='right')
df3= df3.drop(['K1_', 'K2_', 'K3_'], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

Comment: This does not give OP's expected result, unfortunately.

Comment: The result is missing a row with index `2011-01-11`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That row was not common to the dataframes; so will not show

Comment: If you see OP's desired output, it is necessary. You'll have to do an outer join, if you really insist on merging.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't fill with 0, because the original dataframe elements might not always be 0. Also your column prefixes are incorrect?